# Knockoutjs bind model to template created with ko.renderTemplate

Tags: knockout.js

What I'm trying to do is create a DOM node, render a template with ko.renderTemplate overwriting the created node and then, in that template both be able to get data from a specific model AND from the viewModel $root.

Ex:

```
var data = new ModelData();
var domNode = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(domNode);
ko.renderTemplate('template', data, {}, domNode, 'replaceNode');
```

And the template could look like:

```
<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <span data-bind="text: DataFromModel"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.DataFromViewModelRoot">
    </ul>
</script>
```

In this case, I don't get any data from $root.DataFromViewModelRoot, because it thinks the $root-data is the ModelData (and I understand why, I just don't know how I should do it).

What I'm trying to accomplish with this is that I need to create a modal-window (bootstrap) from a template, and then I want to be able to display different content in that modal depending on what data I "send in to it". I also need to be able to create multiple modals and that's why I need to create a new DOM node.

Comment: I would pass all data to template `ko.renderTemplate('template', { Data: data, DataFromViewModelRoot: DataFromViewModelRoot }, {}, domNode, 'replaceNode');` then in the template `<span data-bind="text: Data.DataFromModel"></span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: $root.DataFromViewModelRoot">`

Answer (score 5):

This is a little bit different than your specific question, but here is an alternative way to work with a bootstrap modal.

You can use a custom binding that wraps both bootstrap's `modal` and the `template` binding.

The binding might look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
        var modal = valueAccessor();
        //init the modal and make sure that we clear the observable no matter how the modal is closed
        $(element).modal({ show: false, backdrop: 'static' }).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modal)) {
                modal(null);
            }
        });

        //template's name field can accept a function to return the name dynamically
        var templateName = function() {
            var value = modal();
            return value && value.name;
        };

        //a computed to wrap the current modal data
        var templateData = ko.computed(function() {
            var value = modal();
            return value && value.data;
        });

        //apply the template binding to this element
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { template: { 'if': modal, name: templateName, data: templateData } }, context);

        //tell KO that we will handle binding the children (via the template binding)
        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        //show or hide the modal depending on whether the associated data is populated
        $(element).modal(data ? "show" : "hide");
    }
};
```

Now, you would bind a single modal on your page like:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" data-bind="modal: currentModal"></div>
```

`currentModal` would be an observable that you populate with an object that contains a `name` (the template name) and `data`.

The way that this works is that if `currentModal` is populated, then the modal is displayed using the current template and data. If `currentModal` is null, then the modal is closed.

Here is a sample for how this would work: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/NJtu7/

Comment: Hi, this is actually how I did it before. But I need to be able to have multiple modals (modal opening a modal). I'm using https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal to make that look okey.

Answer (score 1):

I have an improved version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16160300/2630724 to share:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, vm, context) {
        var modal = valueAccessor();

        //init the modal and make sure that we clear the observable no matter how the modal is closed
        $(element).modal({show: false}).on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
            if (ko.isWriteableObservable(modal)) {
                modal(null);
            }
        });

        var template_computed = ko.computed({
            read: function() {
                var value = modal();
                return value ? value : {'if': false};
            },
            disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element
        });

        //apply the template binding to this element
        return ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { template: template_computed }, context);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var data = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        //show or hide the modal depending on whether the associated data is populated
        $(element).modal(data ? "show" : "hide");
    }
};
```

All you need in addition to this is one element for the modal

```
<div class="modal fade" data-bind="modal: currentModal">
</div>
```

somewhere on your page and then you open a dialog by writing to the currentModal observable and you close the dialog by nulling it: currentModal(null)

I'm using bootstrap 3.0-rc1 knockout 2.3 in there which allows a computed as template name :)

Thanks @rp-niemeyer for posting this!