# Knockout - binding dynamic ajax data to bootstrap modal - Updated

Tags: knockout.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I've been working off this question : [Knockoutjs bind model to template created with ko.renderTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150143/knockoutjs-bind-model-to-template-created-with-ko-rendertemplate/16160300)

I've nicked the fiddle in the above question and added a function to one of the items data property to show myself that I can have a function rather than hard-coded data.  Here's that fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/stevedavey/22w7o5a3/

Here's a deeply simplified version of the vm data structure

```
data: { 
        tasks: [ { 
                  taskId: 1, 
                  taskName: 'Renew Widget' 
                  parts: [ { 
                             genericPartId: 1, 
                             genericPartName: 'Widget',
                             partOptions:[{ 
                                            optionId: 1
                                            manufacturerNo: 'AD12',
                                            cost: 100
                                          },
                                          { 
                                            optionId: 2
                                            manufacturerNo: 'LY77',
                                            cost: 75
                                          },
                                          { 
                                            optionId: 3
                                            manufacturerNo: 'F8UI',
                                            cost: 135
                                          }
                                         ]
                           }
                         ] 
                 } 
               ]  
       }
```

So in my main page there's a list of tasks with a list parts underneath.  Each part, if it has more than one part option, has an anchor that when clicked should show a modal with the part options displayed.

In reality the part options are expensive to retrieve so I wanted as part of the click to make an ajax call to populate the partOptions observable.  This would lead to the modal being displayed.  However, the use of RPN's implementation of the modal custom binding makes it more complicated than just responding to a click to make an ajax call.  I've now added RPN's suggested implementation of onDemandObservable that should help with the asynchronicity.  The code looks like this:

```
ko.onDemandObservable = function (callback, target) {
var _value = ko.observable();  //private observable

var result = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        //if it has not been loaded, execute the supplied function
        if (!result.loaded()) {
            callback.call(target);
        }
        //always return the current value
        return _value();
    },
    write: function (newValue) {
        //indicate that the value is now loaded and set it
        result.loaded(true);
        _value(newValue);
    },
    deferEvaluation: true  //do not evaluate immediately when created
});

//expose the current state, which can be bound against
result.loaded = ko.observable();
//load it again
result.refresh = function () {
    result.loaded(false);
};

return result;
```

};

Here's a snippet of the ko-mapping code I've got in my vm:

```
                    "potentialParts": {
                        create: function (partItem) {
                            var part = ko.mapping.fromJS(partItem.data);
                            part.isOilPart = ko.computed(function () {
                                var OIL_GENART1 = 3224;
                                var OIL_GENART2 = 1862;
                                return part.partNo() === "|PPL|" && (part.genArtNumber() === OIL_GENART1 || part.genArtNumber() === OIL_GENART2);
                            });

                            part.data = ko.onDemandObservable(self.getPartsSelectorData, part);

                            part.modalTemplateName = ko.observable("PartSelectorDialogTemplate");

                            return part;
                        }
                    }
```

and here is the getPartSelectorData code:

```
    self.getPartsSelectorData = function() {
    var that = this;

    var url = "/Worksheet/GetPotentialPartSelectorData?partId=" + that.partID() + "&quoteItemOrdinalId=" + that.quoteItemOrdinalId();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function (result) {
            that.data(ko.mapping.fromJS(result.data));
        },
        error: function () {                
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE: Fixed the updating of the That.data property.  In the update of the modal custom binding handler there is actual data available.

The modal backdrop now shows but I don't see any modal content.  I suspect my template isn't being rendered.  I'm hazy with templates so I've probably messed something up there.

Comment: `part.data = ko.observableArray();` and then do the Ajax call, whose `then` clause will set the contents of `part.data`.

Comment: Thanks, I know how to make an async ajax call. Could I ask respectfully for you to re-read the question and indicate what I've missed in my question that doesn't make my actual request clear.  Thanks.

Comment: In what way does it not work? If the click binding makes the ajax call, and the ajax call sets what your fiddle has as `currentModal`, you should have the behavior you want.

Comment: The problem with that part was the fact I was using a plain computed observable.  I needed to set the deferEvaluation for that to true.  I ended up using the onDemandObservable to wrap up all the necessary functionality.  Thank god for RPN! Now it's my template not being rendered.  I'll take a further look and edit my question as applicable.

Comment: Ah, yes. It is unfortunate that `deferEvaluation` is false by default.